# Access Nuxt custom plugin from Composition API

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs, vue-composition-api

I am using VueClipboard in my nuxt project.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-clipboard2

I have a plugin file vue-clipboard.js

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueClipboard from 'vue-clipboard2';
Vue.use(VueClipboard);
```

It is imported into nuxt.config

```js
plugins: ['@/plugins/vue-clipboard'],
```

This sets up a global variable $copyText and in nuxt **without the composition API** I can do something like

```js
methods: {
  async onCopyCodeToClipboard() {
    const code = 'code'
    await this.$copyText(code)
  },
},
```

However inside the setup using the composition API (@nuxtjs/composition-api) when I write a function I do not have access to this.$copyText

```js
const onCopyCodeToClipboard = async () => {
  const code = context.slots.default()[0].elm.outerHTML
  // -> Can't use this here - await this.$copyText(code)
}
```

So how do I make `$copyText` available to use inside the composition API?

Comment: you should use useContext for get plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work via the Nuxt `useContext()` method:

```js
import { useContext } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'

export default function () {
  const { $copyText } = useContext();

  $copyText('code');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using nuxt bridge, you should directly import the useContext from useNuxtApp() like:

```js
 const { $copyText } = useNuxtApp()
```

https://nuxt.com/docs/bridge/bridge-composition-api#usecontext-and-withcontext